# How to run PHP in Javascript (browser)?

Tags: javascript, php

This is not another of those questions, this is about parsing and interpreting PHP in the browser with JS.

How can you run PHP in JavaScript? I am not asking about running PHP in the server and then send the resulting string to the browser as JavaScript. I am literally talking about JavaScript parsing and running PHP.

This might be useful in many places:

- An express Node.js app that has to use a PHP module.
- A small REPL for the browser that does not need a whole VM per instance. Ideal for learning PHP.
- Making a template engine for a static site constructor.

I've searched around and found [`php-parser`](https://github.com/glayzzle/php-parser) and [`babel-preset-php`](https://gitlab.com/kornelski/babel-preset-php), but nothing to run it. Ideally I'm looking for something like this, though I couldn't find anything through Google/SO/etc:

```
// No server needed, "just" Javascript parsing PHP
alert(php(`<?= "Hello world" ?>`));
```

If you know a better way than my own answer, please feel free to share it! I'm very curious about what the community thinks.

Comment: your just spamming your blog.

Comment: It was not my intention, link to my blog removed! I think this question/answer can stand on their own and might be interesting to the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible! Using the two libraries mentioned in the question, dissect `babel-preset-php` and reuse some parts to transpile PHP to Javascript, and then eval the Javascript. Here is a working demo, feel free to write some basic PHP in the `<textearea>` and press `run` to run the PHP in the browser:

```js
const $ = sel => document.querySelector(sel);
$('#horrible').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  eval($('#horrible textarea').value);
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2.1em;
  padding: .3em .6em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: .2em;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 90%;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .3em .9em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #0074d9;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: .2em;
  width: auto;
  user-select: none;
  margin: .3em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-radius: .2em;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0) inset;
}
```

```html
<form id="horrible">
<textarea style="min-height:150px">const vars = { icon: &#x27;&#x1F389;&#x27; };
const out = php(&#x60;&#x3C;?= &#x22;for fun! &#x22;.$icon ?&#x3E;&#x60;, vars);
alert(out);</textarea>
<button data-tooltip="Are you sure? Like, 100%? There is no coming back">EVAL()</button>

<script src="https://francisco.io/blog/running-php-in-javascript/php.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the actual code snippet used to build the `php.js` file linked above:

```js
import parser from 'php-parser';
import translator from './translator';
import generator from '@babel/generator';

const run = (code, opts) => {
  // Make a closure so that `out` doesn't collide with the PHP variables:
  let out = '';
  // Define `echo` since it's used in the transpiled JS code for some reason
  opts.echo = opts.echo || (str => out += str);
  // Pretend this is safe. Pro tip: IT IS NOT SAFE
  new Function(...Object.keys(opts), code)(...Object.values(opts));
  return out;
}

export default function (src, opts = {}) {
  const ast = new parser().parseCode(src);
  const file = translator.translateProgram(ast);
  const code = generator(file).code;
  return run(code, opts);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write something in jsvascript . Then it is necessary the javascript code should be in php file i.e. if file name is temp.php

and javascript code should be in script tag.

eg. test.php (your php filename)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunc(){
                alert('<?php echo date("Y/m/d"); ?>');
            }

        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

The above code alerts the date. The above date is a php date function.

Initially, The php server executes the above code and treat JS code as plain text.

and will looks like below when it comes to client/ browser

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunc(){
                alert("2018/06/30");
            }

        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is not about running PHP in the server. Generally developers knows how to do that.

Comment: I understand a similar but different question has been asked thousands of times before, but please re-read the question. It's not one of those! I just highlighted the difference. I am asking how to parse and run PHP in Javascript. I also provide an answer of my own on how to do it.

Comment: Except your answer _doesn't_ "parse and run PHP in Javascript". Your PHP runs on the server and happens to output Javascript.